# Redux-thunk dispatch an action and wait for re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const disabled = (state = true, action) => {
  return action.type === "TOGGLE" ? !state : state;
};

class Button extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.disabled !== this.props.disabled && !this.props.disabled) {
      //  this.ref.focus();  // uncomment this to see the desired effect
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { props } = this;
    console.log("rendering", props.value);
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onClick={() => {
            props.toggle();
            this.ref.focus(); // doesn't work
          }}
        />
        <input
          disabled={props.disabled}
          ref={ref => {
            this.ref = ref;
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const toggle = () => ({
  type: "TOGGLE"
});

const A = connect(state => ({ disabled: state }), { toggle })(Button);

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={createStore(disabled, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
    <A />
  </Provider>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit redux-thunk-promise]

I want to focus the `input` when the checkbox is checked.
However, `this.ref.focus()` must be called only after the component re-renders with `props.disabled === false`, as an `input` with `disabled` prop cannot be focused.

If I do the logic in `componentDidUpdate`, I'm able to achieve what I want. But this is not a clean solution as the logic is specific to the `onClick` handler rather than a lifecycle event.

Is there any other way to accomplish this? (preferably with a working codesandbox example)

Comment: IMO, update in the `componentDidUpdate` is the right way, because re-render and focus is both component's state and behavior, you cannot decouple them cleanly. I would even say you should move the toggle state into the component and just have some callback props for `onToggle` and `onClick`.

Comment: @Avery235 what makes you say "this is not a clean solution as the logic is specific to the onClick handler rather than a lifecycle event"?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do is not rely on refs use state to manage the focus.

This solution instead uses the `autoFocus` prop on the input, and modifies it when the state of the checkbox changes.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const disabled = (state = true, action) => {
  return action.type === "TOGGLE" ? !state : state;
};

class Button extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: false,
    focus: false
  };
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.checked !== this.state.checked) {
      this.props.toggle();
      this.setState({
        focus: this.state.checked
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { props } = this;
    const { checked, focus } = this.state;
    console.log("rendering", props.value, checked);
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onClick={({ target }) => {
            this.setState({ checked: target.checked });
          }}
        />
        <input key={`input_${checked}`} autoFocus={focus} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const toggle = () => ({
  type: "TOGGLE"
});

const A = connect(state => ({ disabled: state }), { toggle })(Button);

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={createStore(disabled, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
    <A />
  </Provider>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit redux-thunk-promise]

---

I'm not sure why, but changing the `autoFocus` prop when the component was previously disabled doesn't trigger the input to be re-rendered. So I've also added a key to the input to force it.

Comment: This results in an extra re-rendering though (compare to using `ref.focus()`) .

Answer (score 2):

This is an hypothetical situation and an open issue in REACT(at the same time NOT) since it is consistent with the HTML spec for autofocus (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes#autofocus). Focus is one of those things that is really tricky to do decoratively because it's part of a shared global state. If 2 unrelated components declare that they should be focused in a single render pass, who is right? So REACT give you the hooks to manage that state yourself but it won't do it for you (thus where the work around like the one your are using came).

But It would be great if REACT added the option to focus on render (could be just autoFocusOnRender), and just have the docs warn people of the behavior if multiple things call for focus at once. Ideally this wouldn't happen because an app with good UX would have specific conditions for calling autoFocusOnRender on different inputs.

I would Suggest what you have done is the best way of doing it :). Hope we get an enhancement for this in REACT.

Comment: How is it not consistent with the HTML spec? What does the HTML spec say that is different from React? "if REACT added the option to focus on render" isn't it already possible with `autoFocus` prop?

Comment: For your 1st point. I havent specified that it is not consistent, it is consistent with HTML spec you might have mis read it, for the 2nd i provided the html spec (PFA link) where in the attributes section there will a documentation on autofocus.

Comment: How autoFocus is functional yet not functional? The best use case to describe this would be when a page has  multiple fields where The autoFocus attribute will only work on the initial render cause the intended behaviour is only to move focus on first render, and this is consistent with the HTML spec for autofocus.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can have confidence that the updated Redux `state` data is there before you perform your `focus()` call, because of the data flow:

1. Dispatch async action `toggleThunk`, and wait for its resolution
2. `then` dispatch synchronous action to update the `state` (new `state` data), and wait for its resolution (?)
3. `then` `focus()` your ref

https://codesandbox.io/s/r57v8r39om

[image: Edit redux-thunk-promise]

Note that in your OP, your `toggle()` action creator is not a thunk. Also, it's a good rule to enforce that your thunks return a Promise so that you can control data flow in the way you're describing.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const disabled = (state = true, action) => {
  return action.type === "TOGGLE" ? !state : state;
};

class Button extends React.Component {
  textInput = React.createRef();

  handleClick = () => {
    const { toggleThunk } = this.props;
    toggleThunk().then(() => {
      this.textInput.current.focus();
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { disabled, value } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.handleClick} />
        <input disabled={disabled} ref={this.textInput} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Action
const toggle = () => ({
  type: "TOGGLE"
});

// Thunk
const toggleThunk = () => dispatch => {
  // Do your async call().then...
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => dispatch(toggle()));
};

const A = connect(state => ({ disabled: state }), { toggleThunk })(Button);

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={createStore(disabled, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
    <A />
  </Provider>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: This is my original approach (see edit), I removed it because it assumes that `this.props.toggleThunk()` will only be resolved after the component re-renders. Why do you think this is a guaranteed behavior and is the behavior documented/referenced anywhere?

Comment: Good question, I'll see what I can find.

Comment: @Avery235 Any news on my updates? I believe my original solution does guarantee the behavior after all. But the other solutions in my edit would also do the job.

Comment: All your solutions seem to revolve around the assumption I mentioned in the above comment, which you did not address.

Comment: I think I did address it:
**1** Dispatch async action and wait for its resolution, **2**
`then` dispatch synchronous action to update the state (new state data that you need to check) and wait for its resolution, **3**
`then` focus() your ref. What am I overlooking?

Comment: `setState` is not synchronous. You should put the `.focus()` call in the callback of `setState`. Also, the actual use case uses another value to determine the disabled prop, which is stored in Redux for persistence, so duplicating it in local state violates single source of truth.

Comment: I meant my original Redux solution, not the component state solution

Comment: I'm not sure how your original solution address the assumption. It only works if the assumption I mentioned in the first comment is true?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this with the prop and a ref. The ref will avoid the need to rerender the input (i.e. for `autoFocus` to work):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const disabled = (state = true, action) => {
  return action.type === "TOGGLE" ? !state : state;
};

class Button extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!this.props.disabled && prevProps.disabled) {
      this.ref.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { disabled } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={!disabled}
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.toggle();
          }}
        />
        <input
          disabled={disabled}
          ref={ref => {
            this.ref = ref;
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const toggle = () => ({
  type: "TOGGLE"
});

const A = connect(state => ({ disabled: state }), { toggle })(Button);

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={createStore(disabled, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
    <A />
  </Provider>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit redux-thunk-promise]

Comment: I need to store the state in redux (to persist it). Could duplicate it in component but that violates single source of truth.

Comment: Isn't it identical to my solution in OP?

Comment: yes, very similar - maybe I didn't understand your question - this is the correct pattern for handling the behavior - you can't set focus to the input until after it's been enabled, which doesn't happen until the render cycle after the action has propagated - make sense?

Comment: I was hoping for a better solution, where you have some way of designing the action dispatcher and the `onClick` handler such that you can call `.focus()` within `onClick` handler. I guess there's no such solution...

Comment: the `onClick` event is the correct place to dispatch the action and the`componentDidUpdate` function is the correct lifecycle moment to detect the state (i.e. store) change and set focus to the input.